# 100% height resize and mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

Doesn't work anymore, if I resize my window but on mobile it works.

```
<script>
var clientHeight = $( window ).height();
$('.container-bigpic').css('height', clientHeight);
</script>
```

if I add this:

```
}).on("resize", function(){ // If the user resizes the window
   winH = $(this).height(); // you'll need the new height value
});
```

It doesn't work on mobiles anymore but will fit the 100vh if I resize the browser window.

Comment: you forgot the pixels -- $('.container-bigpic').css('height', clientHeight+"px");

Comment: you mean like this? the problem is, that it doesn't work on the mobile screen: <script>
var clientHeight = $( window ).height();
  $('.container-bigpic').css('height', clientHeight+"px");
  }).on("resize", function(){ // If the user resizes the window
   winH = $(this).height(); // you'll need the new height value
});
</script>

Comment: for re sizing the window rry the javascript resize function (window.onresize = function(event) {
    --code--
};)

Comment: Does this have to be using JQuery? Why not use CSS media queries? I only mention is because this: on("resize" will fire for every pixel the window moves, that's going to add a lot of resource usage